# Uncaught TypeError: this.$.selector.clearSelection is not a function

Tags: polymer

Here is my layout. Without iron-list it works, but with it it gives me the error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$.selector.clearSelection is not a function

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../common-settings-service/common-settings-service.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<dom-module id="common-settings">
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }

        paper-material {
            background: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .container {
            @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        }

        .windowItem {
            @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        }

        .list {
            @apply(--layout-flex);
            @apply(--layout-vertical);
        }

        .item {
            @apply(--layout-horizontal);
            margin: 16px 16px 0 16px;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

    </style>
    <template>
        <common-settings-service
                id="commonSettings"
                url="/board_service/common_settings/"
                settings="{{settings}}"/>
        <paper-material elevation="1">
            <div class="container">
                <h3> Настройки обработки</h3>

                <h4>Окна</h4>
                <div class="list">
                    <iron-list items="[[settings.timeWindows]]" as="item">
                    <template>
                        <div class="item">
                            Name: <span>[[item]]</span>
                        </div>
                    </template>

                </iron-list>
                </div>
```

While I don't know how to show you live demo I've been able to debug a little iron-list code. The problem is with the last line.

```
clearSelection: function() {
      function unselect(item) {
        var model = this._getModelFromItem(item);
        if (model) {
          model[this.selectedAs] = false;
        }
      }
      if (Array.isArray(this.selectedItems)) {
        this.selectedItems.forEach(unselect, this);
      } else if (this.selectedItem) {
        unselect.call(this, this.selectedItem);
      }

      this.$.selector.clearSelection();    
    },
```

Debugging shows that there is really no such function in selector. And this selector is actually array-selector element from polymer library. And  it have such function in the source code.

Comment: It's better if you could make a live demo

Comment: I agree, show us your code so that we can help you.

Comment: @Flavio Ochoa - you can see all the code. I don't know how to make live demo for polymer code.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I've found the reason for this. They've changed API beetween 1.0.9 and 1.1.1. My polymer was version 1.0.9 and that's why it haven't worked.
I've updated all polymer elements to the latest version and now it works.